# Javascript function called only half of the time

Tags: javascript, html, function, onload

I've seen some similar problems on StackOverflow, but I cannot seem to find one that matches mine.

I'm sort of new to programming, but I've made quite some things already. I'm currently working on merging all of it together into a site. For this, I made a header containing a navigation panel. I had 6 different html pages and I kept repeating the same information for the header, so I figured it would probably be better to insert the header using JS. In that case I would only have to define the header once and have it identical on all html pages. The beginning of the HTML pages is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Main page</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0' />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index css/index style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./index js/index js.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <header id="navPanel">
    </header>
<main>
... page content ...
</main>
</body>
```

Some pages have a script more, but there are no other scripts that target `id="navPanel"`. 
The JS that creates the navigation panel is located in `index js.js`. The code below is the JS that generates the navigation panel:

```
window.onload = function setupNav() {
    let navPanel = document.getElementById('navPanel');
    console.log(navPanel);
    document.getElementById('navPanel').innerHTML = '<nav> \
    <ul class="navigation navLinks" id="navBar"> \
        <div class="navTabletFlex"> \
        <img class="logo" src="./images/Logo.png" alt="Logo" /> \
            <li><a href="./index.html">Home</a></li> \
            <li><a href="./construction.html">To Do List</a></li> \
            <li> \
                <div class="dropdownNav" id="dropdownNav"> \
                    <button class="dropbtn" id="dropBtn">Games</button> \
                    <div class="dropdown-content"> \
                        <ul class="navLinksDropdown"> \
                            <li><a href="./rps.html">Rock Paper Scissors</a></li> \
                            <li><a href="./rpsls.html">Rock Paper \
                                    Scissors Lizard Spock</a></li> \
                            <li><a href="./numguess.html">Random Number Guesser</a></li> \
                            <li><a href="./puzzle.html">Puzzle Game</a></li> \
                        </ul> \
                    </div> \
                </div> \
            </li> \
            <li><a href="./construction.html">About me</a></li> \
            <li><a href="./construction.html">Contact</a></li> \
        </div> \
    </ul> \
    <button class="navBarIcon" onclick="toggleNav()"> \
                <i class="fa fa-bars"></i> \
    </button> \
</nav>';
    hightlightCurrentPage();
};
```

The weird thing is that on index.html, construction.html, and numguess.html the header works normally, while on rps.html, rpsls.html, and puzzle.html it does not. The header is present and when I try to target it using `document.getElementById('navPanel')` in the console I can add things there using `.innerHTML`.

I've tried to place `<script type="text/javascript" src="./index js/index js.js"></script>` just before the `</body>` tag, but to no avail. I cannot find any differences between the working pages and the non-working pages. So my hope is that some of you have some ideas what I can look for.

Edit: 
Below are the other HTMLpages. 
puzzle.html (*not working*)

```
<head>
    <title>Puzzle game</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0' />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./index js/index js.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="./Puzzle app/js/Cell.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="./Puzzle app/js/Puzzle app js.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="./Puzzle app/js/PicturePuzzle.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index css/index style.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <header id="navPanel">
    </header>
... rest of page...
```

rpsls.html (*not working*)

```
<head>
    <title>Rock paper scissors lizard spock App</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0' />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./Rock paper scissors lizard spock app/js/Rock paper scissors lizard spock app js.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./index js/index js.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index css/index style.css" />
</head>

<body onload="getComputerPlays()">
    <header id="navPanel">
    </header>
...rest of page
```

rps.html (*not working*)

```
<head>
    <title>Rock paper scissors App</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0' />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./Rock paper scissors app/js/Rock paper scissors app js.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./index js/index js.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index css/index style.css" />
</head>

<body onload="getComputerPlays()">
    <header id="navPanel">
    </header>
...rest of page
```

construction.html (*working*)

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index css/index style.css">
    <script text="text/javascript" src="./index js/index js.js"></script>

    <title>Under Construction</title>
</head>

<body class="construction">
    <header id="navPanel">
    </header>
...rest of page
```

numguess.html (*working*)

```
<head>
    <title>Random Number Guessing Game</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0' />
    <script src="./Random Number Guesser/js/Random Number Guesser Script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./index js/index js.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index css/index style.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <header id="navPanel">
    </header>
...rest of page
```

Comment: Without seeing the HTML for the other pages, it's not really going to be possible to determine why the header won't generate for them. Something is different in the HTML if the exact same script is working for some pages but not others

Comment: Why in the world are you adding HTML with an onload? That means you want to add it every single time. Just put it in the actual HTML. If you still want to do this, please give us the full code of every page (use hastebin.com)

Comment: If you're worried about having to write the header for each html file separately, a better solution would probably be using a templating language. Haters gonna hate, but php might be a good starting point.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the developer console? Are there any errors on loading the page? On Chrome you can access the developer console by pressing F12.

Comment: https://hastebin.com/oqiwaracuf.xml

https://hastebin.com/ijemidixoh.xml

https://hastebin.com/camicayosa.xml

https://hastebin.com/karavigame.xml

https://hastebin.com/nubenuforo.xml

https://hastebin.com/aguginemes.xml

https://hastebin.com/gakagusefi.js

Comment: There are no errors. I've tried adding console.logs inside and outside of the js function. The function isn't accessed on the pages where it doesn't load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside your js files, place their contents inside of a function call which listens for the correct moment to properly spring to action:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  console.log('page is fully loaded');
  // somewhere here goes your content
});
```

Whats going on is that the browser starts parsing the data it sees from top to bottom and begins processing it as soon as possible. But by placing the JS you wrote  inside that function you're telling the browser  "hey call this once you're done reading and loading the page".

source:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event

Comment: But that wouldn't make sense if it works for half of the pages right?

Comment: why wouldn't it? I can't see your JS but you're describing what sounds like this very issue that i described in the  answer. If this doesn't solve it, then you can move to another thing. Till then this  is  probably the  root cause of misfiring and improper loadings.

Comment: I just tried it after having a short toilet break. Excuse me for replying too briefly. It does work. However, can you explain a little further why this only happens for half of the pages?

Edit: also, mozilla shows that window.onload has a similar function to window.addEventListener('load', (event).. Did I do something wrong in using window.onload?

Comment: its roughly the same.  Anyhow, like i said before its a design feature of the browser the way it is processing and parsing the data as it is coming over the interwebs. Think of it like a robot thats actively reading all the files and things that get thrown at it. So  in your case it got the files at different times and ran some of that content, but that content was depending on the other files to be all together. So what is happening now is youre left wondering why this robot is  behaving as such. What this fix does is tell that robot "hey man slow down and wait for all the other files first"